# Regex to extract a particular value from the String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby, rubygems

In this console I have the data which is to be extracted from this string
[image]

**String Obtained in the rails console**

```
  Ace Janitorial Service. Inc.                                                                  Invoice
4901 MORENA BLVD. STE 907

SAN DIEGO, CA 92117 US
(858) 270-7004
rbeckerley@acejanitorialsd.com

www.acejanitorialsd.com



            BILL TO

            Lab Fellows, Inc.
            11011 N Torrey Pines Rd,
            La Jolla, Ca 92037




INVOICE #            DATE              TOTAL DUE            DUE DATE           TERMS             ENCLOSED
31104                02/15/2021        $1,251.92            03/17/2021         Net 30





DATE                  DESCRIPTION                                         QTY                RATE           AMOUNT

01/19/2021            Refrigerator Cleaning                                  2               20.00            40.00
                      Clean interior of Refrigerators

02/01/2021            Janitorial Services                                5,564                0.10           556.40
                      2x's a week Labs

02/01/2021            Janitorial Services                                8,194                0.08           655.52
                      2x's a week office space
Thank you for your continued business!!
                                                             BALANCE DUE                             $1,251.92
```

I have tried with the below code

```
def extract_invoice_no(msgBody)
      pattern = [ "invoice_number", "invoice number", "invoicenumber", "InvoiceNumber", "Invoice number", "Invoice Number", "Invoice_Number", "invoice #", "invoice#", "Invoice #", "Invoice#", "InvoiceNo", "Invoice No", "Invoice no","Invoice_No", "invoice no", "invoice_no", "invoiceno"]
      invoiceNo = '';
      pattern.each do |each|
        if (msgBody.include? each)
          invoiceNo = msgBody.split(each)[1].gsub(':','').strip.split(" ")[0]
          puts 'invoice no ', invoiceNo
          break
        end
      end
      return invoiceNo
    end
```

**Requirement:** I need to extract the INVOICE # (Invoice Number) from the below output using ruby code.

**Output Obtained:** DATE

**Output Required:** 31104

Any help could be really useful for me to proceed further.

Comment: Would be great if, instead of image, you could put the contents in form of text.

Comment: You can try something like [`INVOICE\D+(\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/baKOFy/1/) to get the invoice number

Comment: @GurmanjotSingh added the string format which I have received

Comment: The invoice number is on the next line, no the following characters

Answer (score 0):

Every pattern starts with `invoice` or `Invoice`.

So you could downcase your text, split around `/^invoice/`, get the second element.
You then get the second line, split again, and get the first "word" of the line following `invoice`:

```
msgBody.downcase.split(/^invoice/)[1].lines[1].split[0]
#=> 31104
```